# Boundaries of subsets of simply-connected domains

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology, gt.geometric-topology

I am trying to prove the following assertion:  Let $B$ be a simply-connected set, and let $B' \subsetneq B$ be a proper open connected subset. Then, there exists a point $x \in \partial B'$ of the boundary such that there is a basis of neighborhoods of $x$ in $B$ whose intersections with $B'$ are connected.

This seems like it should be true.  For example, in the one-dimensional case, a proper open subinterval of an interval always has an endpoint satisfying this property, whereas for a circle, one can take the complement of a point $x \in S^1$, and the boundary point $x$ does not have the property in question.

I am happy if one takes the special case of $B$ a manifold, or even a product of intervals.

Comment: False. Take B = C (complex plane) and B' = C minus [0,infty) and x = 1.

Comment: @mme: if I understand the question correctly, it asserts an existence of such an $x$ rather than claiming that it's true for any $x$ on the boundary, i.e. I don't think you are allowed to pick $x=1$ :-)

Comment: There is a 1-dim simply-connected continuum B that may serve as a counter-example.

Comment: Thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems if you take $B=\mathbb{R}^2$ and $B'$ the complement of the closure of $\Big\{\big(x,\sin\big(\frac{1}{x}\big)\big);x\in(0,\infty)\Big\}$ this is a counterexample. (Added bonus: $B'$ is also simply connected)